# Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Code 401

Tags: azure, github

I've deployed my little django app, but can't deploy it continously. Every time I see this error message, while deploying from GitHub. I am using student account, so mb that could be a reason?

```
Run azure/webapps-deploy@v2
Package deployment using ZIP Deploy initiated.
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Unauthorized (CODE: 401)
```

[image]